# .Net Registry Security Permissions - User with Permissions cannot access Registry

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, registry

For my .net application i have a mechanism that creates a special user on the local machine. I then create the Registry / Directory entries and assign this newly created user full access to the appropriate Sub Keys / Folders.

For my test i use Impersonation to setup the enviroment to run under this new user, and then run some manipulations on the Registry / Directory sections.

I use the following code to create my registry section (Run as Admin):

```
        RegistryAccessRule rule = new RegistryAccessRule(LOGON_USER_NAME, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow); 
        RegistrySecurity security = new RegistrySecurity();
        security.AddAccessRule(rule);

        //Create Test Sub Key in Registry with permissions for the MicaUser
        root = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(SUB_KEY_ROOT, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        root.SetAccessControl(security);

        RegistryKey key = root.CreateSubKey(SUB_KEY_DELETE, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

        root.Close();
        key.Close();
```

Then when i attempt to manipulate the register under an impersonated user:

RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SUB_KEY_ROOT);
root.DeleteSubKeyTree(SUB_KEY_DELETE);

This causes a permissions exception "Cannot write to the registry key".

The directory manipulation is fine, and works as expected, however the registry permissions fail. I checked the registry and the user has been granted full permissions to the sub key.

Error: "Cannot Write to Registry Key"

NOTE: The registry manipulation works fine under an Admin user, so the code is correct.

Any thoughts?

Regards

Tris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

I have figured out what the problem was with regards to accessing the various sub items, both Directories and Registries. It appears the ACL is applied ONLY to child items and not to the root item. The issue below is a question as to how to solve this problem:

[C# - Windows ACL - Applying Inherited Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411743/acl-applying-inherited-permissions)