# C# code to set a remote share to inherit permissions from its parent directory

Tags: c#, permissions, directory, directoryinfo, inheritance

I have two machines, call them client and server, in a Windows domain. The server has a shared directory which can be accessed from the client machine. I want to run a C# application on the client which sets the permission on this share to inherit the permissions of the share's parent directory on the server. How do I do this?

I have tried code along the following lines, but I don't think it has the right effect:

```
DirectoryInfo shareDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo("\\server\share");
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = shareDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
directorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
InheritanceFlags iFlags = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;
FileSystemAccessRule accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, iFlags, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);
bool modified;
directorySecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, accessRule, out modified);
if (modified)
{
    Directory.SetAccessControl(name, directorySecurity);
}
```

I guess I don't understand why I have to create a FileSystemAccessRule for the directory - how can I just say inherit from parent?

Thanks for any help! Martin

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411743/c-windows-acl-applying-inherited-permissions

Comment: Yes, I did, but it didn't help - unless I have misunderstood this post, it's basically doing the same thing that I currently do: adding access rule for a user. What I think I ought to be able to do is just say "inherit from parent" without creating a rule any particular user.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the folder to inherit from parent by using [SetAccessRuleProtection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx)

```
DirectoryInfo targetFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\share");
DirectorySecurity folderSecurity = targetFolder.GetAccessControl();   // Existing security
folderSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, true);                // This sets the folder to inherit
targetFolder.SetAccessControl(folderSecurity);
```

EDIT: The msdn document explains that if false is sent as the first argument, then the second argument is ignored.