# Unable to check 'Include inheritable permissions' on new directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows, inheritance

I'm attempting to create new directories and set permissions programatically. I've been able to create the directory, apply the permissions for individual users and groups, and update most inheritance and propagation settings. However, I am unable to use the code to check the *Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent* option that is found in the Window GUI interface (see below).

I've tried using alternate values of the Inheritance and Propogation flags, as well as the `SetAccessRuleProtection` arguments, but I can't seem to find any permutation that works.

Code example:

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;

//...

string dir = @"C:\MyTestFolder";

DirectorySecurity dirSec = new DirectorySecurity();

dirSec.AddAccessRule(
    new FileSystemAccessRule(@"contoso.com\myuser",
        FileSystemRights.FullControl,
        InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
        PropagationFlags.None,
        AccessControlType.Allow));

dirSec.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, true);

Directory.CreateDirectory(dir, dirSec);
```

Not sure if it is relevant, but I'm using this to create home directories for users, so the plan is to have the user have modify permissions and inherit or add the SYSTEM and Administrators local users/groups with full permissions.

I've tried [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532014/file-permissions-do-not-inherit-directory-permissions) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574196/programatically-removing-include-inheritable-permissions-from-this-objects-par) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411743/c-sharp-windows-acl-applying-inherited-permissions) from here on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to get that pesky box checked. Any ideas?

Edit: Here are the check boxes to which I am referring. Note that these are not my particular screenshots, but are just demonstration.

[image: This image] 
This image shows the greyed out checkbox in the second window, and the accessible checkbox in the third window. In my case, both boxes are unchecked when I create the folder with the above code (and using any variations of the arguments for `SetAccessRuleProtection` or the Inheritance and Propagation flags.

My intent is to have those GUI checkboxes checked (and therefore their appropriate permissions set under the hood) when I create the directory, so that it would appear similar to the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# code to set a remote share to inherit permissions from its parent directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290471/c-sharp-code-to-set-a-remote-share-to-inherit-permissions-from-its-parent-direct)

Comment: @MethodMan - I've tried setting SetAccessProtectionRule to all four combinations of true and false and none of them make any difference. In all cases, the checkbox remains unchecked. I've also tried different variations of the inheritance and propagation flags thinking that maybe one of those is to blame, but so far I'm simply not finding any combination that gets that box checked.

Comment: not sure what you're talking about in regards to `checkbox` you need to seriously show all relevant parts of your code.. you write as if the whole world can see what it is you are looking at.. please edit and update your question with relevant code that pertains to your issue.. thanks

Comment: My apologies for making it unclear, I have added a screenshot which should help clear it up. All relevant code is already provided - all I'm doing is creating a directory and attempting to apply the permissions, not much code should be needed.

Comment: screen shots do nobody any good.. show your code.. it's not `secret` code that you are writing I do not click on links that are unrecognizable sorry

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, that _is_ the code. That's all of it. That code is executed, a directory is created, the user is given permissions to the folder. If you'd like, I can wrap it in a class, but what good would that do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69681/discussion-between-squid808-and-methodman).

Comment: Oh you mean the checkbox in the permissions... ? lol sorry have you stepped thru the code.. or tried running this in `Admin` mode when starting up VS IDE

Comment: The only user that can check the "Include permissions from this object's parent" on the first page is the *owner* of the folder.  The second window allows anyone with the correct NT permissions to modify the value.  So, you should probably try to determine who the actual owner of the folder is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this all comes down to order of operations. It seems that if I create the directory by supplying the `DirectorySecurity` it will create the folder with the Folder Permissions being completely overwritten by what I supply. And, for some reason if I call `SetAccessRuleProtection` to set the folder's inheritable permissions for the DirectorySecurity that I'm supplying *during* creation, it doesn't take.

But, if I instead create the folder first without supplying any permissions information it is created with that box checked off by default, and then I can just add my AccessRule as needed:

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;

//...

string dir = @"C:\MyTestFolder";

//If you update and add the access rules here, it doesn't work

Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

//Now that the folder has been created...
DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir);
dirSec.AddAccessRule(
    new FileSystemAccessRule(@"contoso.com\myuser",
        FileSystemRights.FullControl,
        InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
        PropagationFlags.None,
        AccessControlType.Allow));
//this isn't really necessary at this point, but wouldn't hurt:
//dirSec.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, true);
Directory.SetAccessControl(dir, dirSec);
```

I don't know the reason why it has to be done in this specific order, but if anyone has insight I'd love to hear why. Regardless, this has me working now without issue.

Comment: AFAIK, the underlying CreateDirectory function doesn't provide any way to specify a DACL with inheritance.  Presumably this is a backwards-compatibility restraint, since inheritance was only introduced in Windows 2000.