# Setting a file's ACL to be inherited

Tags: c#, acl

I am looking for a way in c# to reset a file's permissions to be inherited from the parent as if the file was created or copied to that directory.

I can't seem to find anything on this from a *file* standpoint (I found a reference or two for directories, but I can't get them to translate to a file for some reason). [C# - Windows ACL - Applying Inherited Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411743/c-sharp-windows-acl-applying-inherited-permissions), for example. But I am not sure what the value for `LOGON_USER_NAME` is supposed to be and as far as I can get is getting a `System.ArgumentExcpetion` of "no flags can be set"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found the answer over here. [File.Move does not inherit permissions from target directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2930969/486660)

```
var fs = File.GetAccessControl(destination);
fs.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
File.SetAccessControl(destination, fs);
```

---

### Update

While the code snip above does add in the inherited permissions, it **does not** remove any *existing explicit* permissions. My final code looks more like this.

```
string destination = @"<my file>";
FileInfo fileInfo;
FileSecurity fileSecurity;
FileSystemAccessRule fileRule;
AuthorizationRuleCollection fileRules;

fileInfo = new FileInfo(destination);
fileSecurity = fileInfo.GetAccessControl();
fileSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
/*
 * Only fetch the explicit rules since I want to keep the inherited ones. Not 
 * sure if the target type matters in this case since I am not examining the
 * IdentityReference.
 */
fileRules = fileSecurity.GetAccessRules(includeExplicit: true, 
                         includeInherited: false, targetType: typeof(NTAccount));
/*
 * fileRules is a AuthorizationRuleCollection object, which can contain objects 
 * other than FileSystemAccessRule (in theory), but GetAccessRules should only 
 * ever return a collection of FileSystemAccessRules, so we will just declare 
 * rule explicitly as a FileSystemAccessRule.
 */
foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in fileRules)
{
    /*
     * Remove any explicit permissions so we are just left with inherited ones.
     */
    fileSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(rule);
}
fileInfo.SetAccessControl(fileSecurity);
```

---

### Update 2

Or, simply use TGasdf's more concise 3 line solution that is elsewhere on this page...

Comment: I was searching for this for ages .. fs.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false); does the trick :D

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer where the explicit permissions are removed felt a bit too complicated for my taste so I tried to create a new FileSecurity. The following seems to work, and the resulting permissions are to use only the inherited permissions:

```
var fs = new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity();
fs.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
File.SetAccessControl(destination, fs);
```